# redis how to autogenerate next key number

Tags: redis, key, phpredis

I'm crash coursing right now in redis, using 'the little redis book'. 
What's not clear to me is how I can autogenerate key values.

So for example, the book uses this set statement:

```
 set users:9001 '{"id":9001, "email":"leto@dune.gov"}'
```

How can i set things up so that the system keeps track of the next available id?  In this case... 9002?

I know there is a INCR function... But I don't know how to incorporate both of these functions together.

So for example, let's say i do this using the redis-cli:

```
 set mykey 1
 set users:mykey '{"id":mykey, "email":"leto@dune.gov"}'
```

This works on the command line, but I need a way to do this programmatically.  I'm thinking I would:

```
  get mykey
  INCR mykey
  set users:mykey ....
```

Does this seem right?  is there another way to do this? Also how do I programmatically using phpredis?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the right way to do it. But a small change in your approach,
When you do INCR you will get a incremented value returned by redis. you can use it directly in the next command. So it is simply,

```
var counter = INCR key
set users:counter . . .
```

So here you start from the index 1. ie, users:1, users:2 and so on.

Hope this is clear.